# How we can set loading in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How we can set loading in react

I tried using usestate but I don't work
I want to set loading while getting data from api
Before getting data I set

```
const {loading, setloading} = useState (false)
const getdata = () => {
  setloading (true);
  fetch();
}
```

Comment: In your example, `getdata` will call `setloading` and set the `loading` variable to `true`. However, you haven't shown any code that would call this. You should probably initialize `loading` to `true` instead of `false`, then use the `.then(...)` callback of `fetch()` to call `setloading(false)`, which would indicate that the API call is complete and the application is no longer loading.

Answer (score 0):

You could initialize the component in a loading state, then update the `loading` variable to be `false` within the callback of your `fetch` call.

```
  const [loading, setloading] = useState(true);

  fetch("https://myapi").then( (value: Response) => {
    // No longer loading
    setloading(false);

    // Do something with response value
  });
```

It would be a good idea to wrap your `fetch` call within `useEffect` so it only runs on component load.